# Which MacOSX e-mail client allows me to set a custom From address?

Tags: macos, email, thunderbird, email-client

I use a catch-all domain for my email so that mail to e.g. [insert-whatever]@mydomain.example.com goes to me.  So, when I register at some cool site I register as somecoolsite@mydomain.example.com.  This makes it easier for me to identify where spam comes from, and I can easily block it.

I currently use [Thunderbird](http://getthunderbird.com) with the [Virtual Identity plugin](https://www.absorb.it/virtual-id), which supports this scheme fully.  When I reply to a mail sent to anothersite@mydomain.example.com, Virtual Identity sets this address as my From address.  I can also edit the From field directly (just as I edit To and Cc), without having to add the From address to a valid-emails-for-this-account preferences dialogue.

I like this a lot, but Thunderbird have other issues I do not like.  Editing quoted and pasted text may result in weird formatting and random indenting.  This can be quite painful.

Are there any other email clients out there that supports custom From addresses?  I see that at least Mail.app and [Sparrow](http://sparrowmailapp.com/) do not support it.

Comment: In Mail.app, you can set custom *From* addresses by entering a comma-separated list of email addresses in the address field of the account preferences. The downside is that you can't customize it directly when composing an email.

Comment: @fideli: That's *exactly* what I don't want to do, as stated above ;)

Comment: @new242 Ah, my thoughts were that if you don't have too many [insert-whatever] addresses, you could enter them all into the account preferences. But yes, this would be cumbersome to use on-the-fly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Postbox](http://postbox-inc.com/), it's somewhat based on Thunderbird (afaik), but maybe some of your issues are resolved. It supports the virtual identities plugin: [Extensions](http://postbox-inc.com/extensions)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It looked kind of promising, but the editor was even worse. When replying to a mail, previously quoted emails were left out from the editor.